# What does "the string representation returned by ToString is required to take into account the current system culture" means?

Tags: cultureinfo

In the [Microsoft Developer Network documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.exception.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx), there's that sentence in the description of the `Exception.ToString` method:

> Where the exception contains culture-sensitive data, the string
>   representation returned by **ToString** is required to take into account
>   the current system culture.

What does it means? Does it means that if the language of the system is French, then the returned message will be in French?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the text may be displayed to the users so it should be understandable to the users. If they are all French, then it would be a good idea for the message to be in French.

More than that though, they need to understand the terms used in the message. It's not much good talking about array bounds and stack overflows and IO exceptions if the target audience is (for example) hairdressers.